# одинаковые матрицы одним и тем же кодом обрабатываются по разному

Tags: python

```
M = int(input()) #количество узлов
N = int(input()) #количество каналов


matrix1 = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
matrix2 = []
c = []

for i in range(M):
    c.append(0)

for i in range(M):
    matrix2.append(c)

print(matrix1)
print(matrix2)


for i in range(N):
    abc = input().split()
    a = int(abc[0])-1
    b = int(abc[1])-1
    c = int(abc[2])

    matrix1[a][b] = 6
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(matrix1[a][b])
    print(matrix1)
```

Две матрицы: `matrix1` и `matrix2`. Они идентичны, только первая введена вручную а вторая автоматически. Я знаю что есть `numpy`, но мне надо знать, почему они именно в этом примере после обработки дают разный результат?

Comment: в одном из циклов опечатка - for i in range(M), должно быть N?

Comment: `matrix2.append(c)` тут вы напихали одну и ту же ссылку на список `c`, там не копии, а один объект. Поэтому меняя, например `matrix2[0]` вы увидите такое же результат в остальных строках. Нужно или копировать `c`, или создавать его как отдельные объекты, например: `matrix2.append([0 for _ in range(M)])`

Comment: Спасибо вам, я действительно думал что заполняется не ссылками а копиями.

Comment: @gil9red сделайте ответом, чтобы автор мог закрыть вопрос.

Comment: @матвейлукашов, пожалуйста :) Я оформил ответ, и, кст, пишите @<ник>, чтобы адресат получал уведомление о комментарии. Если в комментариях только один написал, то можно не писать с ником -- он все-равно получит уведомление, а когда уже 2 и более написали, то использовать @<ник> :)

Answer (score 0):

Причина в том, что при `matrix2.append(c)`, где `c` является списком (изменяемым объектом), не будет копирования, а будет добавление ссылки на список.

Это приведет к тому, что в `matrix2[0]`, `matrix2[1]`, ...,  `matrix2[n]` будет находиться один и тот же объект, поэтому изменения будут видны во всем массиве, хотя поменяли, например, только в одной строке.

Поэтому, вам нужно, или создавать копии `c` при добавлении или создавать новый список.

#### Вариант с копией.

Можно обернуть `c` в функцию создания списка, тогда будет сделана копия

```
for i in range(M):
    matrix2.append(list(c))
```

Но если у вас в `c` будут другие изменяемые объекты (например списки), то это не скопирует их.

Для полной копии нужно можно использовать функцию из модуля [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

---

#### Вариант создания нового списка.

Можно использовать генератор списка:

```
for i in range(M):
    matrix2.append([0 for _ in range(M)])
```